# Unable to run a command with SSH in a BASH script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, scripting

I'm writing a BASH script to run commands on a Universal Power Supply via a SSH connection. I'm able to SSH to this device and run commands on the terminal. When I run the the script shown below, the script will execute, connect to the device, and immediately close.

BASH Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in $(cat apcIPAddresses.txt)

do
        echo "$x"
        if ping -q -c 2 -W 1 $x > /dev/null; then
                echo "$x is up"
                ssh user@$x -c aes256-cbc upsabout
        else
                echo "$x is down"
        fi
done
```

Output:

```
user@PC1:./apcInfo.sh
192.168.1.10
192.168.1.10 is up
user@192.168.1.10's password:
user@PC1:
```

I tried multiple methods suggested online on running commands with SSH. I expect for the script to return the output of the upsabout command.

Comment: Could you try the following: `ssh -T "user@"host" "upsabout"`, if that does not work, try: `echo "upsabout" | ssh "user"@"host"`.

Comment: It might be that the UPS has an ssh server with limited functionality (what kind of UPS has ssh access??) that automatically starts the login shell. In any case, try both `-T` and `-t` options (individually, not together ;-)

Comment: Can you run that `ssh` command from the terminal?

Comment: This is really, in general, specific to the individual device. Embedded systems generally don't use OpenSSH but instead use smaller/simpler/limited SSH servers; figuring out exactly which usage modes that server supports is an exercise to the reader, but _often_ there's only one channel allowed per transport, and often that transport _must_ be an interactive session, not an individual command.

Comment: @C-nan, the second of those is likely to help, but I'm unclear on the relevant difference in the first one; noninteractive use typically turns off TTY support _by default_.

Comment: BTW, re: `for x in $(cat anything)`, see [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Better practice is something like `while IFS= read -r x <&3; do ...; done 3<apcIPAddresses.txt` (use of FD 3 instead of the default of FD 0 / stdin prevents ssh from being passed the stdin stream with the list of IPs)